# Ionic Cordova camera is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to use ionic cordova camera.

I have below code

**HomePage.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Example">
  <ion-content>
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
</html>
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('HomePageCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $location, $cordovaCamera) {

    $scope.data = {};


    $scope.takePicture = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function (err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }
})
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }
    });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

         .state('HomePage', {
             url: '/HomePage',
             templateUrl: 'templates/HomePage.html',
             controller: 'HomePageCtrl'
         })
         .state('login', {
             url: '/login',
             templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
             controller: 'LoginCtrl'
         });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');  
});
```

**Question:**

When i click to button in order to use camera

I get below exception:

```
 Module 'ngCordova' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Where i miss in above side

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken frome [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/):

> Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file
> before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file (since
> ngCordova depends on AngularJS).

In short words: ngCordova is missing in your index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

when you send the Image in to your database the image is came from camera in base64 string.So,That string you automatically send to the your database.
    Install **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera** in you project

```
var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
$scope.Base64string="data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

write this in your controller and base64 string came in $scope.Base64string but when you send this string one problem came that is you have to store this amount of data in the middle **spaces** came so to neglect the one you will write in services
srting Image="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/sfgdhbygcecechghchchvfhcghfvhv57egdhbgh.........";  
string imagerty = Image.Replace(" ", "+");

Or

in Angularjs
var str = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/sfgdhbygcecechghchchvfhcghfvhv57egdhbgh.........';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('+');
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to define ngCordova script (beetween ionic.bundle.js script and cordova.js script)

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

also you may  need to install whitelist plugin and add meta to index because in some mobile devices it wont work because of centent security policy permission violations

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src 'self' https://*/ http://*/ data: gap: content: 
'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
               script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
               style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

this will allow you to use pictureSelection too